# how to run intern against webdriver on remote machine

Tags: intern

I've setup Intern tests on my local machine.  Now I'm trying to run those tests against a webdriver server on a remote machine.

I've started a webdriver server on the remote machine, with the command:

```
C:\> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
```

I set my intern config options to point to that remote machine:

```
intern.tunnel = "NullTunnel";
intern.tunnelOptions = {
        hostname: "192.168.1.4",
        port: 4444
};
```

That works enough to start firefox on the remote machine, but then firefox navigates to the URL:

http://localhost:9000/__intern/client.html?config=...

That doesn't work, since the port=9000 listener is running on my local machine, 192.168.1.12.  How do I make it navigate back to the URL on my main machine, instead of localhost?

Answer (score 2):

The piece you are missing is to set `proxyUrl` to point back from your remote machine to the machine with the actual code.

So in sum, given `host1` containing the files and `host2` running the Selenium server, you should have the following:

- `intern.tunnelOptions.hostName` set to `host2`
- `intern.proxyUrl` set to `http://host1:9000/`

Comment: Thanks,   I had tried [digdug's proxy option](https://theintern.github.io/digdug/Tunnel.html#proxy) but for some reason I didn't realize there was  a top level setting for proxy too.

So now it works.  Actually, I'm using (selenium grid](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2), so I ended up w/the config:

```intern.tunnel = "NullTunnel";
intern.proxyUrl = "http://host1:9000";
```